# performance http slow down redirects to https

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, ssl, https

I have an SSL Certificate running on my web address.
But I did some speed tests and the problem I get is this:

When I enter in a speed test `domainname.com` I will see there is a 301 redirect to my `https://domain` which causes a slow loading speed.

When I enter `https://domainname.com` directly in a speed test it won't show any 301 redirects and loads much faster.

I'm using wordpress and installed it trough cpanel software with the setup right away for https.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'd be surprised if an HTTP to HTTPS redirect was having any real impact on the load speed. How are you handling the redirect?

Comment: Look at this results I just tested it again;

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160609_3K_1A1N/ this is like domain.com

And this is like https://domain.com
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160609_TK_1A64/

Comment: There is no damage in a HTTP to HTTPS redirect, its the best thing to do so learn to live with it. Make sure al your internal links are https:// (WordPress `site_url()` and deep-links to content like images). Then set up a HSTS response header so browsers cache (remember) they need to access your site through HTTPS.

Comment: I've highlighted some of the paths you had in text. It's important to contrast the most relevant information. Also made some minor text corrections. Nothing too severe but remember a correct text  is easier to read (just like in code).

Comment: might this problem be related to the user, meaning the browser is slow in doing the redirect? Or is it a DNS caching problem? I know this problem, but after going once to the https site, also the http site is fast.